# Debugging getRange error on Range of mutablearray

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging

I am trying to debug this line of code. It is not my code but have to find what is wrong. self.events is an NSMutableArray.

```
- (nullable NSArray<id> *)getEvents:(NSUInteger)numberOfEvents {
    
    if (self.events.count == 0) {
        return nil;
    }
    
    NSLog(@"min = %ld", MIN(numberOfEvents, self.events.count));
    
    return [self.events subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(numberOfEvents, self.events.count))];
    
}

- (NSUInteger)numberOfEvents {
    return self.events.count;
}
```

Error occurs in this line

```
   return [self.events subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(numberOfEvents, self.events.count))];
```

I Get the following exception. I can not reproduce the error. On my side it works ok.

EXC_BAD_ACCESS: count > getObjects:range: >
Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x9f1ffdcac950.

Any help or ideas appreciated!

Comment: Try to debug with Zombies enabled? Seems like a memory issue.

Comment: I enabled Zombies but cant reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are indexed from zero.  If you have an array that has a count of 4, it's indexes go from 0 to 3.

I think you want:

```
return [self.events subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, MIN(numberOfEvents, self.events.count - 1))];
```

Comment: I agree but if it was an index out of bounds the stacktrace would give me index out of bounds error am i right? I might be wrong just askingyou because you are more experienced. The EXC_BAD_ACCESS: count > getObjects:range: > Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x9f1ffdcac950. error. Doesn’t that error mean that is a memory leak?

Comment: Not in Objective-C.  Swift gives you index out of bounds protection, but Objective-C does not.  The system has read in what is supposed to be an address (it probably is looking for an object pointer) and what it read from memory is not a valid address so I throws an exception.  The memory probably contains whatever is lying around after the memory that is storing your array.

Comment: I see at this post that it gives... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22961013/objective-c-slicing-an-array-gives-index-out-of-bounds-error this is different situation?